# Efficient variable watching in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, debugging

I'm currently writing a multi-threaded, high efficient and scalable algorithm. Because I have to guess a parameter for the code and I'm not sure how the calculation performs on a specific data set, I would like to watch a variable. The test only works with a real world, huge data set. It is possible to analyze the collected data after profiling. Imagine the following, simple code example (real code can contain multiple watch points:

```cpp
// function get's called by loops of multiple threads
void payload(data_t* data, double threshold) {
    double value = calc(data);
    // here I want to watch the value
    if (value < threshold) {
        doSomething(data);
    } else {
        doSomethingElse(data);
    }
}
```

I thought about the following approaches:

1. Using `cout` or other system outputs
2. Use a binary output (file, network)
3. Set a breakpoint via gdb/lldb
4. Use variable watching + logging via gdb/lldb

I'm not happy with the results because: To use 1. and 2. I have to change the code, but this is a debugging/evaluating task. Furthermore 1. requires locking and 1.+2. requires I/O operations, which heavily slows down the entire code and makes testing with real data nearly impossible. 3. is also too slow. To use 4., I have to know the variable address because it's not a global variable, but because threads get created by a dynamic scheduler, this would require breaking + stepping for each thread.

So my conclusion is, that I need a profiler/debugger that works at machine code level and dumps/logs/watches the variable without double->string conversion and is highly efficient, or to sum up with other words: I would like to profile the internal state of my algorithm without heavy slow-down and without doing deep modification. Does anybody know a tool that is able to this?

Comment: On Linux, the `gdb` debugger has *watchpoints* (thru its `watch` command), implemented using `ptrace`

Comment: If the function is called by multiple threads, there are possibly multiple locations where `value` is stored / updated, right? Could you create a static array (known location) with N elements, where N = number of threads; then copy `value` into the array location appropriate for the thread that called it? Then you only have to watch that array for all the values. If you don't care if you only have one value it could be a simple location rather than an array - and again you could then watch with `gdb`.

Comment: It certainly stops being highly efficient and scalable once you start doing any of these things.  If you can't use a built-in operating system feature, similar to a performance counter or ETW on Windows, then you need to start thinking about a circular buffer that's read by another thread.

Comment: "requires I/O operations, which heavily slows down the entire code" only if you invoke the I/O from your calculation threads, which you should not do anyway. You should add the watch values to a queue (producer) and get them out in large blocks + dump them to file in another thread (consumer)

Comment: Could you provide me a bit a bigger picture of what kind of Problem you are are trying to trace down? Calculation process errors? Race conditions? For the former, I'd recommend to write unit tests that make sure each calculation step does what it has to do instead of playing with live data. For the latter you should diagnose These kind of things from the design and not from runtime as every Instrumentation will change the runtime behavior and alter the symptoms...

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify the fact that I want to profile the internal state and that it is some kind of profiling and not a unit test.

Comment: Any solution that lets you see the values is going to require I/O.  You can avoid locking by making a file per thread using thread local data.  There is nothing magical about watch points in a debugger.  The debugger will be more overhead than simple I/O.

Answer (score 3):

OK, this took some time but now I'm able to present a solution for my problem. It's called tracepoints. Instead of breaking the program every time, it's more lightweight and (ideally) doesn't change performance/timing too much. It does not require code changes. Here is an explanation how to use them using gdb:

Make sure you compiled your program with debugging symbols (using the `-g` flag). Now, start the gdb server and provide a network port (e.g. 10000) and the program arguments:

```
gdbserver :10000 ./program --parameters you --want --to use
```

Now, switch to a second console and start gdb (program parameters are not required here):

```
gdb ./program
```

All following commands are entered in the gdb command line interface. So let's connect to the server:

```
target remote :10000
```

After you got the connection confirmation, use `trace` or `ftrace` to set a tracepoint to a specific source location (try `ftrace` first, it should be faster but doesn't work on all platforms):

```
trace source.c:127
```

This should create tracepoint #1. Now you can setup an action for this tracepoint. Here I want to collect the data from `myVariable`

```
action 1
collect myVariable
end
```

If expect much data or want to use the data later (after restart), you can set a binary trace file:

```
tsave trace.bin
```

Now, start tracing and run the program:

```
tstart
continue
```

You can wait for program exit or interrupt your program using CTRL-C (still on gdb console, not on server side). Continue by telling gdb that you want to stop tracing:

```
tstop
```

Now we come the tricky part and I'm not really happy with the following code because it's really slow:

```
set pagination off
set logging file trace.txt
tfind start
while ($trace_frame != -1)
set logging on
printf "%f\n", myVariable
set logging off
tfind
end
```

This dumps all variable data to a text file. You can add some filter or preparation here. Now you're done and you can exit gdb. This will also shutdown the server:

```
quit
```

For detailed documentation especially for explanation of filtering and more advanced tracepoint positions, you can visit the following document: http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Tracepoints.html

To isolate trace file writing from your program execution, you can use cgroups or another network connected computer. When using another computer, you have to add the host to the port information (e.g. `192.168.1.37:10000`). To load a binary trace file later, just start gdb as shown above (forget the server) and change the target:

```
gdb ./program
target tfile trace.bin
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set hardware watchpoint using gdb debugger, for example if you have

```
bool b;
```

variable and you want to be notified every time the value of it has chenged (by any thread)
you would declare a watchpoint like this:

```
(gdb) watch *(bool*)0x7fffffffe344
```

example:

```
root@comp:~# gdb prog
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5-ubuntu
Copyright ...
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapp_socket5_ipaddresses...done.
(gdb) watch *(bool*)0x7fffffffe344
Hardware watchpoint 1: *(bool*)0x7fffffffe344
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x40079f: file main.cpp, line 26.
Starting program: /dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapp_socket5_ipaddresses 

Hardware watchpoint 1: *(bool*)0x7fffffffe344

Old value = true
New value = false
main () at main.cpp:50
50                  if (strcmp(mask, "255.0.0.0") != 0) {
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 1: *(bool*)0x7fffffffe344

Old value = false
New value = true
main () at main.cpp:41
41              if (ifa ->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) { // check it is IP4
(gdb) c
Continuing.
mask:255.255.255.0
eth0 IP Address 192.168.1.5
[Inferior 1 (process 18146) exited normally]
(gdb) q
```